Is it possible to have a kafka consumer in PUSH model?
I did some browsing and found that Kafka can have consumer with PULL model. Is there any extension or external brokers or tools that can be used with Kafka to have consumers in PUSH model instead of PULL manner?
I went through Kafka documentation and found sample codes related to PULL model.

No. Consumers are required to subscribe to topics and poll.
Brokers do not push to consumers. I.e you cannot tell a broker where to forward events.
ksqlDB can do "push queries" to long-lived, connected HTTP clients after it has polled from the brokers.
